# Switching to an open application via BetterTouchTool (making it active)

Tags: keyboard, applications, switching, bettertouchtool, shortcut

Is it possible to *switch* **TO** an *open* application via keyboard shortcut in BetterTouchTool?

Currently I’m using a predefined action “Open Application” instead but it’s not quite the same as I don’t want to switch to the app. if it hasn’t been opened yet.

Answer (score 6):

A free solution: Use BetterTouchTool to trigger an applescript similar to the following, which will activate Safari if it's running, and do nothing if it's not:

```
if application "Safari" is running then
    tell application "Safari" to activate
end if
```

A not free solution: Tie a BetterTouchTool trigger to a [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) macro, which will give you plenty of control over when the application gets activated. The following example would have the same effect as the above AppleScript:

[image: This Keyboard Maestro macro should have the same effect as the AppleScript above]

There are many ways to tie BTT to KM, but the easiest is having BTT trigger the hotkey used by KM (in this case, CTL-OPT-SHIFT-CMD-S).

Obviously, both solutions would work for any application, not just Safari.

Answer (score 2):

`Trigger Predefined Action -> Controlling other applications -> Show/Hide Specific Application` is the best way to accomplish it that I could find.